# Angular animation state strange behaviour

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I cant' fully understand how angular animation states works.

I have two lists. First one with animation, and second with drag n drop. After seconds list change (cdkDropListDropped fired), animation of first First List is fired also. 
Animation always should go from "small" state to "large" and then again to "small". Sometimes it fires up straight from "large" (try two time drag last element to top). Which is very strange

stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9cpned

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the exact reason, but it seems to have to do with Angular's render lifecycle for `*ngFor`. Re-rendering the list items seems to interrupt the animation sometimes. This appears to be fixed by adding a `trackBy` function to the `*ngFor`. That's all I changed here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcxrbs.